# What information should I provide in my answers?

Tags: support, faq

Is there any information that I have to necessarily provide when I answer to a question?
What information do you suggest to provide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the answer describes a hook that must be implemented to accomplish a task, it would help the OP if it is also provided a link to the documentation page. For Drupal core hooks, the link should take to the [Drupal API Reference](http://api.drupal.org/) site; alternatively, [DrupalContrib](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/) contains the documentation for functions implemented by third-party modules.
Similar link should be provided when referring a Drupal core function, or a function implemented by a module.

It is not information that must be provided, but it surely helps who asked the question (and any user who read the answers to that question) if the links to the documentation pages are provided.

Answer (score 2):

When the question is about code, give example code, not just a description of what the code should do.
When possible, give links to the documentation for functions and methods used in the shown code; eventual links to blogs or documentation pages that explain the topic or a wider topic are welcome too, especially if the user needs to know something more than what asked in their questions.